# Find factor primes in haskell

Tags: haskell

Write a function called factor that will take an Integer and determine its prime factors (called prime factorization). The function should take an integer and return a list of integers. This list should be the prime factors of the number, not including multiplicity. For example, the prime factors of 56 are 2 and 7 (even though the full multiplication is 56 = 2<sup>3</sup> × 7 = 2 ×  2 × 2 × 7). What are the prime factors of 175561 and 62451532000?

So far, what I got is:

```
factor :: Int -> [Int]
factor n
  | factors == []  = [n]
  | otherwise = (factors ++ factor (n `div` (head factors)))
  where factors = take 1 $ filter (\x -> (n `mod` x) == 0) [2 .. n-1]
```

but this print the full multiplication, when plug 56 it gives 2.2.2.7 and I want it with no duplication like 2, 7.
How can I filter?

Answer (score 1):

Use `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]`, which removes duplicate elements from lists.
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub